# Prevent CUDA-enabled MPI from checking for CUDA devices

Tags: gpu, mpi, openmpi

The OpenMPI 4.0.5 on our cluster is built with CUDA support, but I want to benchmark pnetcdf without needing CUDA for that. Since I want to do a number of test runs that I can start on like 1/4th of a node and my tests won't make use of the GPUs I wanted to ask if there is a way to suppress the MPI check for CUDA devices. Because when I simply obtain a SLURM allocation without GPUs, I get lots of errors from that alone.

These errors come from hwloc, and can be suppressed with HWLOC_HIDE_ERRORS=1 but I'd like to know if there is a more specific method.

Steps to reproduce:

```
frontend$ salloc -n 16 -t 8:00:00 -A k20200
node$ exec bash -l
node$ module load gcc openmpi
node$ mpicc -o /tmp/hello ~/usr/src/helloworld_mpi.c
node$ srun -n 1 /tmp/hello
CUDA: Failed to get number of devices with cudaGetDeviceCount(): no CUDA-capable device is detected
Hello world!, I'm rank 0 of 1!
node$ HWLOC_HIDE_ERRORS=1 srun -n 1 /tmp/hello
Hello world!, I'm rank 0 of 1!
node$ logout
```

The example code used above is the following but any program without CUDA use is equally useful in this exercise

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#define xmpi(rc)                                  \
  do {                                            \
    int err = (rc);                               \
    if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {                     \
      char msg[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING + 1];         \
      int msg_len;                                \
                                                  \
      if (MPI_Error_string(err, msg, &msg_len)    \
          == MPI_SUCCESS){                        \
        msg[msg_len] = '\0';                      \
                                                  \
        fprintf(stderr,                           \
                "Problem in MPI call: %d = %s\n", \
                err, msg);                        \
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);             \
      }                                           \
    }                                             \
  } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  xmpi(MPI_Init(&argc, &argv));
  int rank, size;
  xmpi(MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank));
  xmpi(MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size));
  printf("Hello world!, I'm rank %d of %d!\n", rank, size);
  xmpi(MPI_Finalize());
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The clean solution is surely to ask the systems people also to install a non-CUDA version of MPI. Provided this isn't made the default I wouldn't see a problem with this.

Comment: Clean for sure, but I only want to install libraries for use by applications which then need cuda support. I'd really like to avoid issues where run-time link paths or other discrepancies of different installs screw up later, i.e. I'd be happier with less rather than more software involved.